# Logging lock acquire and release calls in multi-threaded application

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, decorator, locks

I am trying to debug a multi-threaded Python application that uses various locks.

Rather than place **log.debug(...)** statements all over the shot to track where and when the locks are acquired and released, my idea is to decorate the methods **threading.Lock.acquire()** and **threading.Lock.release()**, and prefix their invocation with something like the following:

```
log.debug("lock::acquire() [%s.%s.%s]" %
          (currentThread().getName(),
           self.__class__.__name__,
           sys._getframe().f_code.co_name))
```

Where **log** is some global **logging** object - for the sake of discussion.

Now ideally the name **"lock"** in the log entry should be derived at runtime, so that irrespective of which lock object these methods are invoked upon the log will output its name, the operation decorated, the current thread, class, and function in which the operation (acquire | release) is called.

**Disclaimer**: I acknowledge that the code given above would not be sufficient for any such decorator implementation. It is only provided just to give a flavour of  what I think could be achieved.

Does anyone know if I can decorate standard library methods, without doctoring the original source code of the **threading** library, i.e., from within my calling application code?

Perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree and there is a better way of achieving the same ends, without using decorators? Many thanks in advance for any guidance if this is indeed the case.

**Solution: (inspired by lazyr)**

The following code logs the lock operations and gives me the name of the method/function calling the lock operation (I am also adapting the code to work with **Conditions** and their additional **wait()** and **notify()** methods):

```
# Class to wrap Lock and simplify logging of lock usage
class LogLock(object):
    """
    Wraps a standard Lock, so that attempts to use the
    lock according to its API are logged for debugging purposes

    """
    def __init__(self, name, log):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.log = log
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.log.debug("{0} created {1}".format(
            inspect.stack()[1][3], self.name))

    def acquire(self, blocking=True):
        self.log.debug("{0} trying to acquire {1}".format(
            inspect.stack()[1][3], self.name))
        ret = self.lock.acquire(blocking)
        if ret == True:
            self.log.debug("{0} acquired {1}".format(
                inspect.stack()[1][3], self.name))
        else:
            self.log.debug("{0} non-blocking acquire of {1} lock failed".format(
                inspect.stack()[1][3], self.name))
        return ret

    def release(self):
        self.log.debug("{0} releasing {1}".format(inspect.stack()[1][3], self.name))
        self.lock.release()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.acquire()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.release()
        return False # Do not swallow exceptions
```

Where the log instance passed to LogLock.**init** was defined with a **logging.Formatter** as follows to given me the calling thread's identity:

```
# With the following format
log_format = \
        logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(threadName)s %(message)s')
```

Comment: If the code you want to monitor is under your control, it would be easier to create a descendant of Lock and have your code use it. Even @decorators are easier when applied on a per-instance basis on the `__init__` constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had just your problem. I set up my logger to automatically log thread name, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722745/logging-between-classes-in-python/4723380#4723380) answer. I found out it was not possible to subclass Lock, so I had to wrap it, like this:

```
class LogLock(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.lock = Lock()

    def acquire(self, blocking=True):
        log.debug("{0:x} Trying to acquire {1} lock".format(
            id(self), self.name))
        ret = self.lock.acquire(blocking)
        if ret == True:
            log.debug("{0:x} Acquired {1} lock".format(
                id(self), self.name))
        else:
            log.debug("{0:x} Non-blocking aquire of {1} lock failed".format(
                id(self), self.name))
        return ret

    def release(self):
        log.debug("{0:x} Releasing {1} lock".format(id(self), self.name))
        self.lock.release()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.acquire()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.release()
        return False    # Do not swallow exceptions
```

I logged the id of the object so I could distinguish between multiple locks with the same name, you might not need it.